# AJAX call. How to make it more dynamic?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

The following code works but, I have to bind the keyup event to every single input on document-ready. Is there a way to change it so that each input type text auto-updates by supplying its own id on keyup? Like a class perhaps?

The following code works but, I have to bind the keyup event to every single input on document-ready. Is there a way to change it so that each input type text auto-updates by supplying its own id on keyup? Like a class perhaps?

I've also commented the code for some clarity.

Here's what I got so far:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pingendo.github.io/templates/blank/theme.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://pingendo.com/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Create global timer outside keyup scope.
        var timer;

        var client_id = '#CLIENT_ID';
        var project_id = '#PROJECT_ID';
        var mainsheet_id = '#MAINSHEET_ID';

        // Random target html element id we want to bind.
        var target_id = '#WTRESRVD';

        // Bind keyup event to target html element id.
        $(target_id).keyup(function() {
            // If timer has been set but user still typing...
            if (timer) {
                // Reset timer and abort function call.
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
            // Set timer to tick in 1 second for 1 second then call function and stop.
            timer = setTimeout(function(event) {
                autoSave(client_id, project_id, mainsheet_id, target_id);
            }, 1000); //wait 1000 milliseconds before triggering event.
        });

        function autoSave(client_id, project_id, mainsheet_id, target_id) {

            var client_id = $(client_id).val();
            var project_id = $(project_id).val();
            var mainsheet_id = $(mainsheet_id).val();


            // Create variable for input text value by id to get all text up to last entered keystroke.
            var target_element = $(target_id).val();
            // Trim it to avoid triggering AJAX call for pressing space bar eg.(nothing to save..)
            var target_element = $.trim(target_element);
            // If there is something other than nothing typed in...
            // This pretty much triggers on every single keyup stroke NOT including spaces, etc..
            // Maybe sanitize sanitize it some more???
            if (target_element != '') {
                // AJAX POST request to run MySQL UPDATE query on this database field ( WTRESRVD ).
                $.ajax({
                    url: "processor.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        postCLIENT_ID: client_id,
                        postPROJECT_ID: project_id,
                        postMAINSHEET_ID: mainsheet_id,
                        postTARGETELEMENT: target_element
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        // setting a timeout
                        $('#status').text('Please wait...');

                    },

                    success: function(data) {
                        // If data return after a successful request isn't an empty string..
                        if (data != '') {
                            // DO something.
                        }
                        // Create variable time to reference later.
                        var time = showTime();
                        // Update div status with last saved time stamp then..
                        $('#status').text("Draft Autosaved " + time).show();
                        // ..fadeOut over 3 seconds. 
                        $('#status').fadeOut(3000);
                    }
                });
            }

        }

    });

    function showTime() {

        var timeNow = new Date();
        var hours = timeNow.getHours();
        var minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
        var seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
        var timeString = "" + ((hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours);
        timeString += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
        timeString += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
        timeString += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";
        return timeString;

    }
  </script>
  <div class="py-2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3 class="">Autosave 4.0 - Cat 2 - Main Sheet</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <form action="tab5_processor.php" class="text-muted">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label">CLIENT ID</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="CLIENT_ID" name="CLIENT_ID" placeholder="input_text_value" type="text" value="111"> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label">PROJECT ID</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="PROJECT_ID" name="PROJECT_ID" placeholder="input_text_value" type="text" value="222"> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label">MAINSHEET ID</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="MAINSHEET_ID" name="MAINSHEET_ID" placeholder="input_text_value" type="text" value="333"> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                  <colgroup>
                    <col width="50">
                    <col width="100">
                    <col width="100"> </colgroup>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>&nbsp;</th>
                      <th>QTY</th>
                      <th>CODE</th>
                      <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>EA</td>
                      <td>
                        <input class="form-control" id="WTRESRVD" name="WTRESRVD" placeholder="" type="text" value="" maxlength="4"> </td>
                      <td>WTRESRVD</td>
                      <td>EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>EA</td>
                      <td>
                        <input class="form-control" id="WTRESRV" name="WTRESRV" placeholder="" type="text" value="" maxlength="4"> </td>
                      <td>WTRESRV</td>
                      <td>EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL AFTER HRS</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="" id="status">Update Status...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Show sample of repeating html. Generally only use one class to initialize event listener and get the corresponding data either from current element, other elements in it's group or from data attributes. `this` inside the event handler references the element the event occurred on

Comment: Original Post updated to include html. Here's a live version.
http://nexlevel.org/autosave4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a common class to all the inputs you want to listen to, or use something more generic like `$('tbody input')`

```
$('tbody input').on('keyup', function(){
   // `this` is input event occured on
   var id = this.id;
});
```

Seems that you don't need most of the arguments in your `autosave()` since you get all but the input id from other fixed elements already inside the function

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to change it so that each input type text auto-updates by supplying its own id on keyup?

You can attach the keyup event handler to each input type text like:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(e) {
     .....
})
```

Refer to: [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

> I have to bind the keyup event to every single input on document-ready. Is there a way to change it so that each input type text auto-updates by supplying its own id on keyup

I would suggest to bien an event on the document aplying the key up for all inputs :

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[type="text"]', function(){
   // whatever you want here
});
```

This way, even if you add new inputs dynamically they will also trigger the event keyup.

Comment: Ok. What if I want only the input type text elements inside of a form to abide by these rule?

Comment: you are changing the $(document) by $('#IdOfYourForm'). the other solutions is to make the second selector more accurate :
$(document).on('keyup', '#IdOfYourform input[type="text"]', function(){